# Can I prevent the reference of a type from being created or used?

Tags: rust

My primary goal is to prevent the reference of a self-defined type from being created. If it is impossible, then my secondary goal is to prevent the using of such reference.

I have a struct that is supported by a page of virtual memory. From time to time, that page may be remapped to a different address, while the content in the page is untouched. The remapping is done by the OS, so the user code is not directly notified when it happens. The OS maintains a reserved register that always points to the remappable page. The user code should follow this register to access the struct. It should not use the (Rust native) reference, because the reference becomes stale after the OS remaps the page.

As an example, assume that the remappable struct is defined as `Remappable`. Special reference types, e.g. `RefField1`, are defined for each field. `volatile_deref()` will follow the reserved register to read the field from the correct address.

```rust
struct Remappable {
    f1: Field1,
    f2: Field2,
    /* ... */
}

impl Remappable {
    pub fn get_ref_f1(&self) -> RefField1 { /* ... */ }
    pub fn get_ref_f2(&self) -> RefField2 { /* ... */ }
}

impl RefField1 {
    pub fn volatile_deref(&self) -> Field1 {
        /* Presumably some inline assembly taking
           atomicity (regarding the remappable page
           address) of reading into account.
           On x86 this may be achieved through
           the usage of segment registers. */
    }
}
```

I have no idea of how to achieve my primary goal, i.e. preventing `&Remappable` from being created.

I gave a naive try to my secondary goal. I did the following, but it could not work, either.

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

impl Deref for &Remappable {
    type Target = ();
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        panic!()
    }
}
```

This is because it gives a conflicting implementation of `Deref`.

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::ops::Deref` for type `&Remappable`
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
7 | impl Deref for &Remappable {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T> Deref for &T
            where T: ?Sized;
```

Is there any way to achieve one of the goals?

Comment: It sounds like you should have a function that accesses the register (and temporarily prevents remapping from happening), then calls a closure with a lifetime-annotated `&Remappable` so that it cannot leak out from the closure (similar to how `crossbeam::spawn` works).

Comment: Or have a method that returns a guard object that `Deref`s to `Remappable` and prevents remapping until the guard is dropped (similar to how `Mutex` works).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prevent the existence of references to a type. Instead, in order to make what you're describing legible to the Rust compiler, you need to make the *container* of that type special. That is, given that

> the OS maintains a reserved register that always points to the remappable page

you should have a data type which represents *that reserved register* (much like, for example, `Box` represents a heap allocation that it manages). That data type is the one which avoids implementing `Deref`.

For illustration, a similar situation appears the `Cell` type in the Rust standard library — because it offers interior mutability, it cannot safely return references to its contents, so every operation on a `Cell` (except for those that know they have exclusive access, which doesn't apply to your situation) must copy data in or out rather than returning references.

Comment: You could also (alternatively or complementarily) only expose methods which take `self` (and return it as-is appropriately). This means a caller would be able to take references but they wouldn't really be able to *do* anything with those references.